# Modifying objects inside of array using .map

Tags: javascript

so i have an array .. with many objects, .. but i want to modify what is inside each object.. but not sure how to go about it.
before

```
[{ filePath: 'stuff/stuff/someplace/',
    path: '/events/places/and/things',
    info:
     { layout: 'event-single',
       permalink: '/events/enigma-2018/',
       title: 'Enigma',
       location: 'Santa Clara, CA',
       description: 'a discription',
       start: 2018-01-30T00:00:00.000Z,
       end: 2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z,
       address: '101 Great American Pkwy, Santa Clara, CA',
     } 
 }]
```

desired after

```
[
     { 
       permalink: '/events/enigma-2018/',
       title: 'Enigma',
       location: 'Santa Clara, CA',
       description: 'a discription',
       start: 2018-01-30T00:00:00.000Z,
       end: 2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z,
       address: '101 Great American Pkwy, Santa Clara, CA',
     } 
 ]
```

this array only has one object for this example, but it would be many objects i would be modifying in the same way ..(edited)
i think .map should be used.. but thats all i know

Comment: Please paste some what you have tried.

Comment: Have you read on MDN what Array.prototype.map does? You can probably solve your problem by loosely copy pasting the examples on MDN

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.map(function(obj) {
    return {
       permalink: obj.info.permalink,
       title: obj.info.title,
       location: obj.info.title,
       description: obj.info.descriptioin,
       start: obj.info.start,
       end: obj.info.end,
       address: obj.info.address,
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [{ filePath: 'stuff/stuff/someplace/',
    path: '/events/places/and/things',
    info:
     { layout: 'event-single',
       permalink: '/events/enigma-2018/',
       title: 'Enigma',
       location: 'Santa Clara, CA',
       description: 'a discription',
       start: '2018-01-30T00:00:00.000Z',
       end: '2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z',
       address: '101 Great American Pkwy, Santa Clara, CA',
     } 
 }]
 
 console.log(myArray.map(function(arrayItem) {
     delete arrayItem.info.layout;
     return arrayItem.info
 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArray = [{
  filePath: 'stuff/stuff/someplace/',
  path: '/events/places/and/things',
  info: {
    layout: 'event-single',
    permalink: '/events/enigma-2018/',
    title: 'Enigma',
    location: 'Santa Clara, CA',
    description: 'a discription',
    start: "2018-01-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    end: "2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    address: '101 Great American Pkwy, Santa Clara, CA'
  } 
}];

// Do it manually:
const mapped = myArray.map(x => ({
  permalink: x.info.permalink,
  title: x.info.title,
  location: x.info.location,
  description: x.info.description,
  start: x.info.start,
  end: x.info.end,
  address: x.info.address
}));

// Or define a set of keep keys and discard the rest:
const keepKeys = [
  "permalink",
  "title",
  "location",
  "description",
  "start",
  "end",
  "address"
];

const otherMapped = myArray.map(x => Object.keys(x.info).reduce((newObj, key) => {
  if (keepKeys.includes(key)) newObj[key] = x.info[key];
  return newObj;
}, {}));

console.log(mapped);
console.log(otherMapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete` command to remove `info.layout`

```js
var a = [{ filePath: 'stuff/stuff/someplace/',
    path: '/events/places/and/things',
    info:
     { layout: 'event-single',
       permalink: '/events/enigma-2018/',
       title: 'Enigma',
       location: 'Santa Clara, CA',
       description: 'a discription',
       start: '2018-01-30T00:00:00.000Z',
       end: '2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z',
       address: '101 Great American Pkwy, Santa Clara, CA',
     } 
 }]
 
 
a = a.map(o => {
 
   var o = o.info;
   delete o['layout'];
   return o;

});

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, it is a generic way to have a new array that contains only the properties of the nested object. Using `typeof`, you check if the value of the property is an object and `Object.assign` to copy the object properties.

```js
var data = [{ filePath: 'stuff/stuff/someplace/',
    path: '/events/places/and/things',
    info:
     { layout: 'event-single',
       permalink: '/events/enigma-2018/',
       title: 'Enigma',
       location: 'Santa Clara, CA',
       description: 'a discription',
       start: "2018-01-30T00:00:00.000Z",
       end: "2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
       address: '101 Great American Pkwy, Santa Clara, CA',
     } 
 }]

var newArray = [];
data.forEach(element => {
var newObj = {};
Object.keys(element).forEach(key => {
  if(typeof element[key] === "object"){
    Object.assign(newObj, element[key]);
    newArray.push(newObj);
  }
})
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

If/when you're comfortable with ES6 syntax you can do this quite concisely:

```
const out = arr.map(obj => {
  const { layout, ...rest } = obj.info;
  return { ...obj, info: rest }
});
```

`map` over the array of objects, use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to grab the `layout` property, and then `...rest` ([spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)) for all the other properties. Then just return the object assigning only the properties gathered in `rest` to the nested info object.

[Here's a demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/wt2pxf6f/).